# Equivalent to asm volatile in Gfortran?

Tags: assembly, fortran, gfortran

Is there an equivalent to Gcc's inline assembly in Gfortran?

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (...)
```

I cannot find anything in the gfortran man page, or the manual.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. The easiest way around it is to have a C function with the **asm**, and then call that C function with ISO_C_BINDING.

Comment: Thanks for the information; we're actually fiddling with a specint test case written in fortran and suspect a performance problem due to stack layout on a certain machine (using Gfortran).  But it seems to be futile to try modifying stack addreasses from within the source code.  Maybe I'll just do it in the assembler sources.