# Completely inverted benchmark result on lambda vs function between GCC and Clang

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, lambda, clang

Consider a slightly modified version of Fibonacci to test the performance between (lambda vs function) (with vs without) captures:

```cpp
size_t fibFn(size_t n) {
  if (n <= 1) { return n; }
  return fibFn(n - 1) + fibFn(n - 2)+1+2;
//                                  ^~~~
//   This is modified so that I can | 
//        capture something outside |
//                    this function |
}
```

When I run this in [Quickbench with Clang 10.0](https://quick-bench.com/q/oNVMd-gMOPPnz1tB-i4UBflxFVU), I got a reasonable result:

**fnNoCapture < lambdaNoCapture < fn << lambda**

When I am just about to conclude that lambda with capture block is extremely slow, however, the result is almost completely inverted when I run this [with GCC 10.1](https://quick-bench.com/q/gVcYOG5ZJD0DNYvzJyppo_TFJGM):

**lambdaNoCapture > fnNoCapture >> fn > lambda**

How is this possible? Is it because the two compilers implemented lambda in different ways?

**EDIT: Even so, it makes no sense to me that lambda (with capture) can be so much faster than that without capture.** The best case a compiler can optimize, in my pov, is to convert a lambda with capture to that without capture (e.g. by inlining variables), if possible.

Comment: Right off the bat, switching optimization to O2 tells a different story.

Comment: @sweenish Sry I'm not sure what you meant by "tells a different story" could u elaborate?

Comment: Are you sure the compiler cannot notice that you are running several times the same computation in a loop and keep just one iteration?

Comment: @MarcGlisse The compiler shall not optimize that. That is how Google Bench library shall work.

Comment: The library cannot change what the language says. Maybe if you made N volatile, or called DoNotOptimize(N) in the loop before calling the function... The result remains surprising, but the ratio reduces.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32974625/1918193 and in particular -fno-optimize-sibling-calls .